# Comparación de dos tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dificultades para poder comparar datos de dos tablas que se encuentran en distintas Base de Datos y servidores distintos estas tablas no tienen los mismo campos pero contienen la misma información

**Ejemplo**

Esta es la consulta de la base de datos **1** donde llega primero la información
es decir la información es correcta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la consulta de la base de datos  **2**  donde la información es obtenida de la base de datos  **1**  y manipulada es decir puede llegar con diferencias

como puedo comparar estas dos tablas si los datos son iguales o distintos 
si son iguales es por que esta correcto

como ven en la imagen el valor de la **bd1** es diferente al price **bd2**
como puedo hacer la comparación que me indique los registros que son iguales y los que no ¿como podría hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Supongo que si *codigo* es igual a *ItemCode* los registros son iguales ¿no? Pero no veo como puedes hacer una comparación así por sql estando los datos en dos BD distintas. Como yo lo veo debes hacerlo por código - obtener los datos y compararlos.

Comment: Ya tengo los datos en un programa que hice mira esta es la pregunta    https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/272819/comparaci%C3%B3n-de-dos-datagridview

Answer (score 0):

Sinceramente sacaría estas comprobaciones de SQL a un lenguaje de programación como C# si te fuera posible, pero si quieres hacerlo por SqlServer primero debes vincular los servicios ([Linked Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)) y una vez que lo hagas puedes hacer algo así:

```
SELECT        
    CASE WHEN t1.Id = t2.Identificador THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IdIguales,
    CASE WHEN t1.Nombre = t2.Descripcion THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NombreIguales,
    CASE WHEN t1.Fecha = t2.Creado THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FechaIguales,
    CASE WHEN t1.Cantidad = t2.Valor THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CantidadIguales
FROM Server1.Db1.dbo.TablaPoC1 AS t1 
    INNER JOIN Server2.Db2.dbo.TablaPoC2 AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Identificador
```

OJO me he inventado los nombres de las tablas y las columnas, pero puedes hacer algo similiar con las tuyas.

Si lo consigues cuéntanoslo, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Ya tengo los datos en un programa que hice en c# mira esta es la pregunta    https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/272819/comparaci%C3%B3n-de-dos-datagridview

Comment: Cierto lo ví posteriormente, es mejor decisión, pero bueno que esta pregunta no se quedara sin contestar y que vieras que era posible de una forma o de otra.

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo